# hoverout too slow

Tags: jquery, text, get, raphael

I'm getting some text leftover on my Raphael canvas as a result of jQuery's hover() function.  I basically want text to appear when I hover over a circle, and then guarantee that it will disappear once I stop hovering over the circle (hoverOut()).

As you can see below, I try to remove() the text on hoverOut(), but it's not getting th job done.  It works fine for removing the rectangle, however.  Is it something to do with the get() request taking too much time?

```
node = paper.circle(value.xpos_init, value.ypos_init, node_rad).attr({"fill": "#ff0000"})
       .hover(function(e){
                posx = e.pageX - $('#canvas').offset().left;
                posy = e.pageY - $('#canvas').offset().top; 
                createMenu(posx,posy,"10");
              },
              function(){
                menu.remove();
                menu_deg_cent_text.remove();
              });

function createMenu(x,y,id_in)
{
  menu_x = 100;
  menu_y = 60;
  menu = paper.rect(x,y,menu_x,menu_y).attr({"fill":"white","stroke":"red"});
  $.get("../php/text.php", {id : id_in},
    function(data){
    menu_deg_cent_text = paper.text(x+(menu_x/2),y+(menu_y/2),"test_text");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using Raphael to make the tooltip box, I highly recommend using native Javascript. A floating  element handles things like styling and wrapping the text much better.

```
node = paper.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({"fill": "#ff0000"})
    .hover(function(e) {
        //if you want to calculate position by mouse
        //posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        //posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop-15;
        posx = this.attr('cx');
posy = this.attr('cy') - this.attr('r');        
        document.getElementById("tip").style.top = posy + "px";
        document.getElementById("tip").style.left = posx + "px";
        document.getElementById("tip").style.display = "block";
    }, function(e) {
        document.getElementById("tip").style.display = "none";
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jLSUa/1/

As for putting an AJAX call inside a mouseover event: Seems very unwise. Can you load the mouseover text ahead of time?

Comment: Best advice here was that doing and Ajax request in a hover() was not the best way to do this.  Just made some changes and it's working great!  Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @Chirs
how to make the tool tip always visible