# Cross - browser issues using Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, raphael

I am creating a rectangle element in raphael JS as a tooltip on an SVG circle element generated by raphael JS. I am unable to access the coordinates of the center of the circle (which I need to place the rectangle tooltip) using the following code in Internet Explorer..

```
var c = {};
c.x = parseInt(c_element.node.attributes[0].nodeValue);
c.y = parseInt(c_element.node.attributes[1].nodeValue);

//code for the rectangle element tooltip
r = paper.rect(c.x,c.y,50,50);
```

Its working fine in Firefox.. But in IE, the tooltip gets created at the upper left corner of the div enclosing my raphael JS paper and not on the center o the circle as desired..

How do I solve this cross-browser issue? Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for certain why IE doesn't like this, but there's a much easier way:

```
c.x = c_element.attr("cx");
c.y = c_element.attr("cy");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G77Zw/1/)

If you log the Raphael object to the console, you can check out the "attrs" property to see what's in there. Different for every type of Raphael object.

While we're all here: I highly recommend using an absolutely positioned div for your tooltips. HTML handles things like wrapping text and resizing the tooltip to accomodate different amounts of text much more easily than the SVG text element. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994031/hoverout-too-slow/13995065#13995065). (Whatever you use, you'll still need to access the coordinates of the circle.)

Comment: thanks for the workaround... it works... IE did not recognize the nodeValue property i was trying to use..